# Reputation graph only partially filled

Tags: bug, google-chrome, reputation-graph

When I view a *large* selection (12+ months) of my daily reputation graph in my profile under the latest version of Chrome, only portions of the content is shown:

[image]

Chrome version: 51.0.2704.103 m

This does not seem to happen with an up-to-date Firefox:

Firefox version: 47.0

[image]

Comment: The lines are too narrow to be seen.

Comment: @TIPS: Then where your Google glasses, as Firefox sees them... :-o

Comment: @Werner It's simply a difference in how the browsers render lines too narrow. Firefox apparently bumps them up to always be 1px, whereas Chrome will just hide them depending on where they are located on the *x* axis. The system generates a valid SVG image - how it gets rendered in the end is not up to us.

Comment: @animuson: Hmmm. Strange that this surfaces only now though...